# The open native mobile app from the browser (iOS 13)

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, deep-linking, ios13, url-scheme

I have a code on the website which was checking the user agent and depending on OS to do the navigation into a native app.

```
function openPage(webUrl, appUrl) {
    var loadedAt = +new Date;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var res = +new Date - loadedAt;
        if (res > 1000) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            // Try launching the website which will navigate you into the app store
            window.location.href = webUrl;
        }
    }, 250);
    // Try launching the app using URL schemes
    window.location.href = appUrl;
}
```

everything works fine till iOS v13. right now if the user go to my site then on the phone will be opened the first native app and then app store with this app.
Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @VamsiKatakam only setting the `interval` into 2sec.

Comment: You mean we need to increase setinterval to 2000?

Comment: @VamsiKatakam yes, and after that just believe that it will work fine